# "Can I merge as a guest ?"

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts

I found an unregistered user that created (at least) four unregistered user accounts.
He wasn't aware of that, so I asked him if he wants these accounts to be merged.

But is this possible for unregistered users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> No. The procedure is: user registers one, the other gets merged into it.

[The source](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/800491#800491) is an SE employee. Although the statement is somewhat dated, it makes sense: SE should not have to expend effort maintaining cookie-based accounts that will likely get lost or split again in the future.

Comment: In other words: if the user won't take the time to register, then SE won't take the time to merge the user's unregistered accounts.